# Constructor overload with and without destructured interface in TypeScript, to allow positional or named args

Tags: typescript

I have a class with some required attributes and some optional attributes (which I want to be `undefined` when not set, as there's no default value). With optional args, there are a lot of parameters, so I would prefer to be able to name them for clarity, while without the optional args, I'd like to make it concise to construct. So, I want to be able to construct it using either named attributes in an object, or as positional arguments:

```
export interface ParamInterface {
  a: number;
  b: number;
  c: number;
  d?: number;
  e?: number;
  f?: number;
}

export class MyClass {
  a: number;
  b: number;
  c: number;
  d?: number;
  e?: number;
  f?: number;

  constructor({a, b, c, d, e, f}: ParamInterface);
  constructor(a: number, b: number, c: number, d?: number, e?: number, f?: number) {
    this.a = a;
    this.b = b;
    this.c = c;
    this.d = d;
    this.e = e;
    this.f = f;
  }
}
```

In other words, I want to be able to call:

```
new MyClass(1, 2, 3); // d, e, f will be undefined
new MyClass({a: 1, b: 2, c: 3}); // d, e, f will be undefined
new MyClass({a: 1, b: 2, c: 3, d: 4, e: 5, f: 6}); // d, e, f will be set
```

And then I want this to *raise an error*:

```
new MyClass(1); // First three args required
```

When I do this, though, I get an error that `This overload signature is not compatible with its implementation signature.`

Is there any way to make it compatible, or another way to achieve what I'm after?

Comment: Would this solution work for you? https://tsplay.dev/WY4lEm

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your constructor implementation type must be supertype of all declarations, like following:

```js
export interface ParamInterface {
  a: number;
  b: number;
  c: number;
  d?: number;
  e?: number;
  f?: number;
}
export class MyClass {
  a: number;
  b: number;
  c: number;
  d?: number;
  e?: number;
  f?: number;

  constructor({ a, b, c, d, e, f }: ParamInterface);
  constructor(a: number, b: number, c: number, d?: number, e?: number, f?: number);
  constructor(...values: [ParamInterface] | [a: number, b: number, c: number, d?: number, e?: number, f?: number]) {
    if (values.length == 1) {
      const { a, b, c, d, e, f } = values[0];
      // assign values
    } else {
      const [a, b, c, d, e, f] = values;
      // assign values
    }
  }
}
```

Here we have two constructor declarations:

```js
constructor({ a, b, c, d, e, f }: ParamInterface);
constructor(a: number, b: number, c: number, d?: number, e?: number, f?: number);
```

and one implementation:

```
constructor(...values: [ParamInterface] | [a: number, b: number, c: number, d?: number, e?: number, f?: number]) {
  // ...
}
```

Type declaration can be a little simplified:

```js
export interface ParamInterface {
  a: number;
  b: number;
  c: number;
  d?: number;
  e?: number;
  f?: number;
}
type TupleParameters = [a: number, b: number, c: number, d?: number, e?: number, f?: number];

export class MyClass {
  // all fields

  constructor({ a, b, c, d, e, f }: ParamInterface);
  constructor(...values: TupleParameters);
  constructor(...values: [ParamInterface] | TupleParameters) {
    // unchanged
  }
}
```

Comment: good answer but just gona point out that the overload here is pointless. the implementation is all you need.

Comment: The only downside of this is that the error you get for `MyClass(1)` is `Argument of type 'number' is not assignable to parameter of type 'ParamInterface'.`, which is not super easy to understand vs. `Expected 3-6 arguments, but got 1.`

Comment: @bryan60 Yeah, it still works without the overloads, but FYI for future readers: the error message you get from `new MyClass(1)` is different if you delete the overloads: `Argument of type '[1]' is not assignable to parameter of type 'TupleParameters | [ParamInterface]'.
  Type '[1]' is not assignable to type '[ParamInterface]'.
    Type 'number' is not assignable to type 'ParamInterface'.` So just a minor difference